# What files does the Gnome Tweak Tool act on (when changing the Typing settings)?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I've saved the output of

```
$ xmodmap -pke
```

in ~/.map1.
Then, I have changed some settings through the Gnome Tweak Tool (say, to keep it simple, I swapped Esc and Caps Lock).
Then I again saved the output of

```
$ xmodmap -pke
```

this time into ~/.map2.

~/.map1 and ~/.map2 are different. And they are different exactly in the way I was expecting. The differences correspond to the keys I have changed.

However I was not expecting the following:
I have disabled all the changes made within the Gnome Tweak Tool, and I have loaded map2 with

```
$ xmodmap ~/.map2
```

I was expecting the same behavior achieved with the changes made with the Gnome Tweak Tool. But this is not the case. (That is now in the Gnome Terminal there is no difference of behavior whatsoever compared to the default settings. Within applications instead Esc key works correctly as Caps Lock, but it doesn't turn on the light of Caps Lock. And finally Caps Lock key seems to perform both the Esc and Caps Lock function).

So the following question arises: What are the files that the Gnome Tweak Tool is acting on?

It would be extremely useful for me to understand how things work here since I want to perform some changes that the Tweak Tool doesn't allow me to do and I'm not able to achieve them with xmodmap.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The files altered by `gnome-tweak-tool` are `~/.config/dconf/user` (this is the `dconf` database, a binary file where most user settings are stored) and various other configuration files under `~/.config` (these are all text files)

In this particular case - changing the typing settings - `gnome-tweak-tool` alters the `xkb-options` in the `dconf` database. It's easy to check that if you monitor the database with

```
dconf watch /
```

and then open `gnome-tweak-tool` and make <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> an additional <kbd>Esc</kbd> you'll get an output like

```
/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options
  ['caps:escape']
```

Comment: Thanks for the step towards the truth. Does this mean that if I want to do the same changes without using gnome-tweak-tool I should I directly modify the binary file ~/.config/dconf/user ? This doesn't seem good news :D

Comment: @gptrst - no; I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish over there (I suspect your Q is a XY question) but anyways you're not supposed to even touch that binary file. _There are tools that have been designed to read/write to that file_ namely `dconf` and `gsettings`. As a side note: `xmodmap` is an obsolete tool and _gnome3_ mostly ignores it. If you want to implement more advanced settings then `xkb` is the right tool.

Comment: Yes it was an instrumental question in order to understand how to do those kinds of changes. Thanks for the note.

Comment: @don_crissti: I'm came here looking to find which files contain Gnome's configuration (especially at the user level) so that I could copy that between my systems using SaltStack and maintain a consistent environment on all my machines.  I suppose I'll just have to run gsettings commands, but passing in text files is a lot more convenient (which, of course, is why I was exploring the possibility).

Comment: @nomen - see if [this helps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/426348/22142)...

Comment: @don_crissti: hey, thank you.  I haven't tried it yet but it looks promising.

Comment: wow never heard of that watch cmd, it's amazing thanks