# How do I use the plain-text mode of dconf?

Tags: gnome, dconf

By default, `dconf` stores its configuration in a binary format, inconvenient for using with version control.

[`dconf`](https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-overview.html) notes that there is a configuration setting for dconf that enables a "bi-directional" plain text mode that effectively mirrors the binary database with a plain text file.

Unfortunately, it gives little guidance on how to use this very promising-sounding functionality.

What is the most straightforward way to enable this?

Answer (score 18):

It's all there (except the part with saving the current settings to that text file):

> On startup, `dconf` consults the `DCONF_PROFILE` environment variable. If
> set, `dconf` will attempt to open the named profile, aborting if that
> fails. If the environment variable is not set, it will attempt to open
> the profile named "**user**" and if that fails, it will fall back to an
> internal hard-wired configuration. `dconf` stores its profiles in text
> files. `DCONF_PROFILE` can specify a relative path to a file in
> `/etc/dconf/profile/`, or an absolute path (such as in a user's home
> directory).

and

> A "`service-db`" line instructs dconf to place the binary database file
> for the user database in `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`. Since this location is not
> persistent, the rest of the line instructs `dconf` how to store the
> database persistently. A typical line is `service-db:keyfile/user`,
> which tells `dconf` to synchronize the binary database with a plain text
> keyfile in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/dconf/user.txt`. The synchronization is
> bi-directional.

So, the text file in question is `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/dconf/user.txt` which usually corresponds to `~/.config/dconf/user.txt`.
First, save your current settings to that file (obviously, this is not needed for a new user):

```
dconf dump / > ~/.config/dconf/user.txt
```

then append the `service-db` line to the profile (as root):

```
mkdir -p /etc/dconf/profile
printf '%s\n' 'service-db:keyfile/user' >> /etc/dconf/profile/user
```

Now, restart your session and the two files will be in sync.

Comment: In Debian 9, the needed `dconf` binary can be installed with `apt install dconf-cli`.